AWS lambda layer cloudformation returns no changes to deploy
I am storing lambda layer code in s3 in zip file. This file is updated each time I am making changes in the code. First deployment succseed, but now when I am trying to update it I am getting message that there are not changes to deploy. I checked file in s3, it is containing changes.
cloudformation template:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  CommonLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      LayerName: "common-lib"
      Description: ""
      Content:
        S3Bucket: artifacts-8473625
        S3Key: layer.zip
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9


I was able to fix it by adding parameter to layer description which is updated with each deployment.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  LatestLambdaLayerVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: v1
    Description: lambda layer latest version
Resources:
  CommonLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      LayerName: "common-lib"
      Description: !Sub "Common layer ${LatestLambdaLayerVersion}"
      Content:
        S3Bucket: artifacts-8473625
        S3Key: layer.zip
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9

